# Syntax-Rule syntax

Tags: scheme, racket

I've been looking over the syntax for defining a syntax rule however I am still stuck.

I want to define a rule with this signature: (define-syntax-rule (for {val in lst} return res).

Basically it simply applies map given a val and a lst.  But I am struggling with the syntax. This is what I've come up with so far..
....
(syntax-rules ()
    ((for val in lst)
     (map (val lst))))
...

The input would be something like:

(for {val in  '(0 1 2 3 4)}
          return (- val  1)
  )

and output (-1 0 1 2 3), as if map were called on the list.

Comment: You can't use `define-syntax-rule` since you have literals in the definition (ie the `in` and `return`). @GoZoner's answer (if you add parens around the `(val in list)`) gives you what you want. (And in Racket, curly braces are the same as regular parens.)

Comment: By the way, Racket comes with [`for/list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for/list#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29) which does the same thing as what you are trying to define. `(for/list ([val '(0 1 2 3 4)]) (- val 1))` => `'(-1 0 1 2 3)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This gets it done:

```
(define-syntax for
  (syntax-rules (in return)
    ((for val in list return exp)
     (map (lambda (val) exp) list))))

> (for x in '(0 1 2 3) return (- x 1))
(-1 0 1 2)
```

Essentially this is exactly as you've described.  You need `in` and `return` declared as literals.